# Access to script has been blocked by CORS policy while using a Font Awesome Kit

Tags: html, font-awesome

I've been following the Font Awesome guides how to use their kits, but when I inserted this code at the end of my `body` tag, I get an error, and I can't use any icons.

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4c00a89bc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is the full HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="icon" href="imgs/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="imgs/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scss/main.css">
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Facebook<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4c00a89bc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the error message:

```
Access to script at 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4c00a89bc.js' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4c00a89bc.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Any idea?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i

Comment: Not really. As far as I understand, I should add headers somehow to my cross origin request, but all I have is a oneliner <script> tag, which somewhy gets blocked, although based on the Font Awesome website it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like JavaScript Debug server caused the problem, that I was using because of the Live Edit plugin. As I restarted the server, the script worked. Also, if I just opened the html file, it worked properly. But the problem always occur at first start of the JavaScript Debug server, when it opens up the browser.

A quick note: put the script rather between the head tag, because it inserts a stylesheet into the html file.

(I am using JavaScript Debug server in phpStorm)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out that I added domain restriction of my font awesome kit, which you can configure on the Font Awesome website. I added mydomain.com, while the correct way is to add *.mydomain.com to allow any subdomain in my website to use the font awesome script. The problem went away once I fixed the error.

You can check the domain setting of your kit in your Font Awesome account to see if it is the cause of the CORS blocking problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use your own font awesome kits. Here is the script you used copied from w3schools.
`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4c00a89bc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Use your own. I used the above script but it does not work, make an account on font awesome the will provide a kit (cdn link). It will work. I solved it by using my own kit.